# Does the Talmud say mishenichnas for Adar to allude to Moshe?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, adar

The Talmud say "mishenichnas" for Adar and not just "nichnas". I understand Hebrew grammar of course, but someone suggested there's an allusion to Moshe from the mishe prefix. Is there any Rabbi that has mentioned this?

Comment: גרסינן בתענית דף כ"ט כשם כשנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה, כך כשנכנס אב ממעטים בשמחה https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.685.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en